# Writing Tiling window manager in Python

Tags: python, window-managers, tiling, window-management

I have been using Awesome Tiling window manager for over 6 months now, and quite happy with this.

I would like to write my own Tiling window manager as a weekend project and for hackfun. I noticed that Xmonad and dwm are very small. I am aware of [Qtile](http://qtile.org/) a python window manager.

I don't know where to begin. Should i read and understand any Xorg manual/api? and Is there any Python libraries for window management? Please suggest how to proceed with writing a tiling window manager.

It will be great if you can share any similar experiences in writing window manager.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Qtile code yet?

Comment: It helps if you understand [XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/), then you can start looking at the [Python bindings](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/XcbPythonBinding/).

Comment: @larsmans I have not read Qtile code yet, i will check that one out.

Comment: The way I did it was to take an existing code, I chose aewm and then spent about a month going over everything inside it to learn how it was working. My intent was only to write a C++ window manager so I have no experience doing this in Python. I also looked quite a lot at the X11 headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need some X client library.  I suggest having a look at [python-xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/), a pure Python implementation of the client side of the X protocol.  It includes [plwm](http://plwm.sourceforge.net/), an example implementation of a minimal window manager written in Python.